# math range error - is there a way to further limit this algorithm to avoid

Tags: algorithm, math, primes

Working on project Euler problem (26), and wanting to use an algorithm looking for the prime, p with the largest order of 10 modulo p.  Essentially the problem is to look for the denominator which creates the longest repetend in a decimal.  After a bunch of wikipedia reading, it looks like the prime described above would fulfill that.  But, unfortunately, it looks like taking the very large powers of 10 results in an error.  My question then is : is there a way of getting around this error (making the numbers smaller), or should I abandon this strategy and just do long division (with the plan being to focus on the primes).
[of note, in the order_ten method I can get it to run if I limit the powers of 10 to 300 and probably can go a bit long, which goes along with the length of a long]

```html
import math

def prime_seive(limit):
 seive_list = [True]*limit
 seive_list[0] = seive_list[1] = False
 for i in range(2, limit):
  if seive_list[i] == True :  
   n = 2
   while i*n < limit :
    seive_list[i*n] = False #get rid of multiples
    n = n+1
 prime_numbers = [i for i,j in enumerate(seive_list) if j == True]
 return prime_numbers

def order_ten(n) :
 for k in range(1, n) :
  if (math.pow(10,k) -1)%n == 0:
   return k

primes = prime_seive(1000)
max_order = 0
max_order_d = -1
for x in reversed(primes) : 
 order = order_ten(x)  
 if order > max_order :
  max_order = order
  max_order_d = x

print max_order
print max_order_d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that your numbers get to large when first taking a large power of ten and then computing the value mod n. (For instance If I asked you to compute 10^11 mod 11, you could remark than 10 mod 11 is (-1) and thus 10^11 mod 11 is just (-1)^11 mod 11 ie. -1.)

Maybe you could try programming your own exponentiation routine mod n, something like (in pseudo code)

```
myPow (int k, int n) {
   if (k==0) return 1;
   else return ((myPow(k-1,n)*10)%n);
}
```

This way you never deal with numbers larger than n.
The way it is written you will get a linear complexity in k for computing the power, and thus a quadratic complexity in n for your function order_ten(n). If this is too slow for you could improve the function myPow to use some smart exponentiation.

Comment: It looks like the other person who suggested using the exponentiation operator deleted his post.  That definitely worked.  I like this solution as well, since it is more math-y.  The problem I'm having is with getting negative results to the modulus operation.  For instance 10%11 gets a result of 10 (11*0 + 10), though I can certainly see the 11*1-1 = 10.  I think I might be missing something with this, and a result of -1 is more useful than a result of 10 when multiplied.  Do I just need to write a method that finds negative results for mod?

Comment: What is the problem with getting negative results ? At least in your case it seems that it should not matter ?

Comment: From a quick read of wikipedia, it looks like there are multiple possible procedures for finding the modulus of a mod n, with a = n*q + r, and the absolute value of r < absolute value of n.  It looks like the % operator in python allows abs(r) <= abs(n).  I could just write a method that checks for r < n, and if not return n-r.  Very interesting.  Thank you.

Comment: I think the comment in my answer confused you. Negative modulus is not the important piece. Assume you are to compute 10^7 mod 7 (for a change). You start with 10^1 = 3 mod 7. Then 10^2 = 10*3 = 30 = 2 mod 7. Then 10^3 = 10*(10^2) = 10*2 = 20 = 6 mod 7. Then 10^4 = 10*(10^3) = 10*6 = 60 = 4 mod 7. Then .. down to 10^7.

Comment: So you are right about modulus and the undefined sign but this should not matter here. As long as you work mod n you don't care whether you are getting positive or negative numbers. I think my exemple with 10^11 was just poorly choosen...

Comment: That makes sense - I never noticed that there is a multiplicative property to the modulus operation, but that really makes it powerful and a lot easier.   It keeps the numbers much smaller. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize the python's [builtin pow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) function includes an optional third argument for the modulus? Python already does all this for you.